# Calculate percentage agreement between values in every row

Tags: r, tidyverse, icc, irr

I'm trying to calculate the intra-class correlation between two raters and multiple subjects. However, I also want to be able to determine the raters' agreement for each and every subject so I can determine what areas have high agreement/low agreement and what may be bringing the score up/down.

I understand I cannot calculate the icc between two raters on *one* subject, but finding the percentage agreement between values on each row (subject) will provide me with specific information.

*Note: The values are continuous integers, not factors*

My data currently looks like:

```
subject  rater1  rater2
1        val1    val2
2        val3    val4
3        val5    val6
4        val7    val8
```

I would like to mutate another column 'agreement' that calculate the percentage agreement *by row*. So, it will essentially look like this:

```
subject  rater1  rater2  agreement
1        val1    val2    agreement_val1 %
2        val3    val4    agreement_val2 %
3        val5    val6    agreement_val3 %
4        val7    val8    agreement_val4 %
```

I understand I would use this to mutate:

```
df %>% mutate(agreement = ???)
```

I'm just trying to figure out the calculation and how it can apply per row/observation/subject. Thanks everyone

EDIT1: I essentially want to use something like the agree() function per row.

This doesn't work, but something of this nature:

```
df %>% mutate(agreement = agree(each row))
```

EDIT2: Some of you guys wanted me to provide an example.

In this example, there are two raters (rater1 and rater2). They are both rating how long (in seconds) an animals performs particular behaviors. The data frame looks like:

```
behavior  rater1  rater2
run       48      59
stand     23      91
sit       389     401
sleep     288     290
```

So, the "subjects" are the animal's behaviors. I could run an ICC() or icc() test, but that would give me a value based on the agreement between both raters on *all* behaviors. However, I want to be able to see how both raters agree/disagree within *each individual* behavior. Hopefully, this makes sense.

Comment: Have you researched any packages to do it? When I google for R packages, I tend to look under the CRAN or Bioconductor labels; for this, [`"CRAN" "ICC"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+icc) (quotes *necessary*) suggested the aptly-named [`ICC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ICC/index.html) package; while it has not been updated recently, I suggest you look at that.

Comment: Could you share an example with some numbers and expected results? I am not sure what kind of calculation you are trying to perform.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide actual data with numbers and corresponding expected output.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the information! I'm looking at the CRAN documentation right now. Honestly, I haven't discovered the ICC package until you mentioned it, so I appreciate it!

Comment: @denisafonin Just provided an example

Comment: @RonakShah Just provided an example

Answer (score 0):

```
library(psych)

ratings <- data.table(
  rater1 = c(3,3,3,4),
  rater2 = c(3,6,4,6),
  rater3 = c(2,1,4,4)
)

ICC(ratings)

# Call: ICC(x = ratings)
# 
# Intraclass correlation coefficients 
#                          type          ICC   F df1 df2    p lower bound upper bound
# Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 -0.000000045 1.0   3   8 0.44       -0.34        0.72
# Single_random_raters     ICC2  0.107142840 1.6   3   6 0.29       -0.15        0.73
# Single_fixed_raters      ICC3  0.157894727 1.6   3   6 0.29       -0.29        0.81
# Average_raters_absolute ICC1k -0.000000136 1.0   3   8 0.44       -3.07        0.89
# Average_random_raters   ICC2k  0.264705847 1.6   3   6 0.29       -0.66        0.89
# Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k  0.359999984 1.6   3   6 0.29       -2.04        0.93
# 
#  Number of subjects = 4     Number of Judges =  3
```